# Filling a <Label> with JSON in react?

Tags: json, reactjs

I have a file called data.json and in it i have an object called "Labels". I'm trying to fill the labels in my form with the elements in the JSON object.

JSON Object:

```
 "Labels": [
    {
      "siteName": "Site Name"
    },
    {
      "siteAdd": "Site Address"
    },
    {
      "siteCounty": "Site County"
    },
    {
      "Location": "Site Location"
    },
    {
      "gps": "GPS: Entrance/Exit"
    },
    {
      "w3w": "W3W: Entrance/Exit"
    },
    {
      "information": "Information"
    },
    {
      "email": "Site Email"
    },
    {
      "number": "Site Phone Number"
    },
    {
      "Categories": "Site Category(s)"
    },
    {
      "times": "Opening Times"
    },
    {
      "fees": "Admission Fees"
    },
    {
      "access": "Accessability"
    },
    {
      "text": "Text Narrative"
    },
    {
      "text-header": "Header"
    },
    {
      "text-content": "Content"
    }
  ]
```

FORM:

```
<Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="form">
                {/* General Information */}
                <FormGroup row>
                    <Label for="siteName" id="siteName" sm={2}></Label>
                    <Col sm={10}>
                        <Input type="text" name="siteName" id="siteName" placeholder="" />
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup row>
                    <Label for="siteAddress" sm={2}>Site Address</Label>
                    <Col sm={10}>
                        <Input type="textarea" name="siteAddress" id="siteAddress" />
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup row>
                    <Label for="" sm={2}>Site County</Label>
                    <Col sm={10}>
                        <Input className="form-control" type="select">
                            { counties.map(c => (<option key={c.value} value={c.value}>{c.display}</option>))}
                        </Input>
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <hr/>
                {/* Location Information */}
                <p className="heading">Location</p>
                <FormGroup row>
                    <Label for="gps" sm={2}>GPS: Entrance/Exit</Label>
                    <Col sm={10}>
                        <Input type="text" name="gps" id="gps" placeholder="entrance 3 words , exit 3 words" />
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup row>
                    <Label for="w3w" sm={2}>W3W: Entrance/Exit</Label>
                    <Col sm={10}>
                        <Input type="text" name="w3w" id="w3w" />
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <hr/>
                <p className="heading">Information</p>
                <FormGroup row>
                    <Label for="siteEmail" sm={2}>Site E-mail</Label>
                    <Col sm={10}>
                        <Input type="email" name="siteEmail" id="siteEmail" placeholder="example@example.com" />
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup row>
                    <Label for="siteNumber" sm={2}>Site Phone Number</Label>
                    <Col sm={10}>
                        <Input type="tel" name="siteNumber" id="siteNumber" placeholder="" />
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup row>
                    <Label for="siteCat" sm={2}>Site Category(s)</Label>
                    <Col sm={10}>
                        <Input type="text" name="siteCat" id="siteCat" multiple />
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup row>
                    <Label for="openTimes" sm={2}>Opening Times</Label>
                    <Col sm={10}>
                        <Input type="text" name="openTimes" id="openTimes" />
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup row>
                    <Label for="fees" sm={2}>Admission Fees</Label>
                    <Col sm={10}>
                        <Input type="textarea" name="fees" id="fees" />
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup row>
                    <Label for="access" sm={2}>Accessability</Label>
                    <Col sm={10}>
                        <Input type="text" name="access" id="access" />
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <hr/>
                <p className="heading">Text Narrative</p>
                <FormGroup row>
                    <Label for="txt-header" sm={2}>Header</Label>
                    <Col sm={10}>
                        <Input type="textarea" name="txt-header" id="txt-header" />
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup row>
                    <Label for="txt-content" sm={2}>Content</Label>
                    <Col sm={10}>
                        <Input type="textarea" name="txt-content" id="txt-content" />
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup check row>
                    <Col sm={{ size: 10, offset: 2 }}>
                        <Link to="/newSite/tours"><Button className="btn-primary">Tours &rarr;</Button></Link>
                    </Col>
                </FormGroup> 
            </Form>
```

So far I have tried:

{ labels.siteName }
Using document.getElementbyID and changing the value.
Even when I console.log it it's being returned as undefined. I'm using json loader to import it into my react component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `labels`, as imported through `json-loader` is an *array of objects* and **not** an *object filled with key-value pairs*.  Given the way that you seem to want to use your `labels` object - that is, as a bunch of key-value pairs, I would recommend that you restructure your JSON data to look like the following:

### labels.json

```
{
  "Labels": {
    "siteName": "Site Name",
    "siteAdd": "Site Address",
    "siteCounty": "Site County",
    "Location": "Site Location",
    "gps": "GPS: Entrance/Exit",
    "w3w": "W3W: Entrance/Exit",
    "information": "Information",
    "email": "Site Email",
    "number": "Site Phone Number",
    "Categories": "Site Category(s)",
    "times": "Opening Times",
    "fees": "Admission Fees",
    "access": "Accessability",
    "text": "Text Narrative",
    "text-header": "Header",
    "text-content": "Content"
  }
}
```

This way, you can actually access each label based on the given key. So, if you did:

```
import labelData from './labels.json'
const labels = labelData.Labels
```

Then, you can access your labels using `labels.siteAdd` or `labels.information` and so on.

Here is a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/64yrvp422k) that shows this code in action.

---

On a separate note, if you are the one in control of writing up your `labels.json` file, I would make the following recommendations to you, as you might find it will make your life easier in the future:

- Be consistent about how you name your keys. I notice that you have `information` but then you also have `Categories` - why is one capitalized while the other one isn't? Just to save yourself from possible typos or not being able to remember if you capitalized or not, stick with one or the other and be consistent.
- Since you know you would like to access your labels with something like `labels.information`, then don't use hyphens in your keys (like in `text-header`). You'll find that you **can't** use `labels.text-header` but instead need to use `labels['text-header']`.

Comment: You are a life saver! Thanks so much. Also thanks for the tips, I'm very new to React and working with JSON in general. This is all for college. I'll do my best to improve. Thanks again

Comment: @TiernO You're welcome! I'm glad I could help! If this answer worked out for you, please consider accepting it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`Labels` is an array of objects. You could reduce that to a regular object to make it easier for you.

```js
const labels = obj.Labels.reduce((acc, label) => {
  Object.keys(label).forEach(key => {
    acc[key] = label[key];
  });
  return acc;
}, {});
```

Then you could use this object like you outlined in your question:

```js
<Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="form">
  {/* General Information */}
  <FormGroup row>
    <Label for="siteName" id="siteName" sm={2} />
    <Col sm={10}>
      <label>
        {labels.siteName}
        <Input type="text" name="siteName" id="siteName" placeholder="" />
      </label>
    </Col>
  </FormGroup>
  {/* ... */}
</Form>
```